# Get day by day repeated data with postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have `transactions` table with columns `id, user_id, currency, amount` and `created_at`;

I want to write function to check in last **x** days transaction with exist amount repeated or not.

For example user makes transaction per 200$ in 5 days, and 6th days wants to make transaction in 250$. Function have to check did user make transaction in last 5 days per 250$ or not. In this example function have to return `false`. Because user breaks rule.

If user want to make transaction with 200$ function have to return `true`;

I have tried with

```
select count(*) from "transactions" where "created_at" >= NOW()- INTERVAL '5 DAY' and "amount"=250 and "currency" = "USD"
```

but this gives me incorrect answer, becouse if user makes a transaction twise a day, this function calculates 5 items in 4 day. If **n** transactions in a day I have to calculate it **1** transaction.

So:

```
id            user_id           currency          amount          created_at
1             1                 USD               200             2021-05-15 16:00:01
2             1                 USD               200             2021-05-16 18:05:28
3             1                 USD               200             2021-05-17 11:33:55
4             1                 USD               200             2021-05-18 12:00:01
5             1                 USD               200             2021-05-18 13:15:01
6             2                 USD               250             2021-05-15 16:00:01
7             2                 USD               250             2021-05-16 18:05:28
8             2                 USD               250             2021-05-17 11:33:55
9             2                 USD               250             2021-05-18 12:00:01
10            2                 USD               250             2021-05-19 13:15:01
```

with this data, query have to return 4 items for user with id 1 and amount 200. Have to return 5 items for user with id 2 and amount 250

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want `count(distinct)`.  You seem to want different values for each user, so that suggests `group by` as well:

```
select user_id, count(distinct created_at::date) as num_days
from "transactions"
where created_at >= NOW()- INTERVAL '5 DAY' and
      amount = 250 and
      currency = 'USD'
group by user_id;
```